# Accessing a website externally from IIS7.5 Windows Server 2012 using port other than 80

Tags: iis-7.5, windows-server-2012

I have two websites, Website1 and Website2.

Website1 is assigned bindings of (server ip):80 and Website2 is assigned bindings of (server ip):4565. No host names have been defined.

Website1 which uses port 80 works fine, I can access the website from any pc in the world with a decent browser using `http://(server ip):80`. I cannot, however, do the same for `http://(server ip):4565` (Website2).

I've searched and searched for solutions but nothing seems to work.

Why is this?

P.S. I am not all that experienced with IIS or server management in general.

Answer (score -1):

you need to do site bindings. have you done that?

http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/mark-newnam/how-to-set-up-site-bindings-in-internet-information-services-iis/

Comment: I have done all that. Another option would be to use different host names on the same port but doesn't the domain (host name) need to be registered? When I tried using host names I can't access either website :/

Comment: Actually using host names throws up a Server Not Found error

Comment: I can't even access the websites from the local server when I use hostnames